# vim omnicppcomplete pattern not found

Tags: c++, vim, autocomplete, omnicppcomplete

I installed vim7.3 on my computer (under windows 7) and i want to use an autocomplete plugin.

I searched a lot and found that Omnicppcomplete is the best for that.

So i followed this tutorial: **[Install OmniCppComplete plugin](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2367-the-autocompletion-c-c-in-vim)**

My _vimrc config file looks like this:

```
set nocp 
filetype plugin on
syntax on
set filetype=cpp

set tags+=C:/Program\ Files/Vim/vimfiles/tags/stl

" build tags of your own project with CTRL+F12 
"map <C-F12> :!ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<CR> 
noremap <F12> :!ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<cr> 
inoremap <F12> <Esc>:!ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<cr> 

" OmniCppComplete 
let OmniCpp_NamespaceSearch = 1 
let OmniCpp_GlobalScopeSearch = 1 
let OmniCpp_ShowAccess = 1 
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteDot = 1 
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteArrow = 1 
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteScope = 1 
let OmniCpp_DefaultNamespaces = ["std", "_GLIBCXX_STD"] 

" automatically open and close the popup menu / preview window 
au CursorMovedI,InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|silent! pclose|endif 
set completeopt=menuone,menu,longest,preview
```

But if i type this an error occurs and dont know why.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
   std::|
}
```

and the error: `-- Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found`

and this [bugfix](http://www.google.hu/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://groups.google.co.uk/group/comp.editors/msg/5bef964303540a4e&rct=j&q=--%20Omni%20completion%20%28%5EO%5EN%5EP%29%20Pattern%20not%20found&ei=vHp_TbafJsaRswaFi-niBg&usg=AFQjCNFyrHSzuih6FIRK7bk83uWEcgjCCQ&sig2=D0ok3JSaA_KVWe7HYLIN8Q&cad=rja) not helps because i already use files which uses `namespace std {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that the `set tags+=C:/Program\ Files/Vim/vimfiles/tags/stl` there is something wrong here:

- `:pwd` -> `c:\Windows\system32`
- copy the tags file to system32
- restart vim

then the following c++ code worked.

Comment: I have the same problem but with Mac. Do you know where I should put tags?