# OmniCppComplete in Vim available only as root

Tags: c++, vim, autocomplete, vim-plugin, omnicomplete

I tried to install OmniCppComplete in Vim and I followed this tutorial:
http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2367-the-autocompletion-c-c-in-vim

I noticed that the plugin works only if I am as a root. Could anyone give me a tip how to make this plugin available for all users?

.Vimrc: (from tutorial)

```
set nocp      
filetype plugin on      

set tags+=~/.vim/tags/stl      
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/gl      
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/sdl      
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/qt4      


noremap <F12> :!ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<cr>      
inoremap <F12> <Esc>:!ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<cr>      

let OmniCpp_NamespaceSearch = 1      
let OmniCpp_GlobalScopeSearch = 1      
let OmniCpp_ShowAccess = 1      
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteDot = 1      
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteArrow = 1      
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteScope = 1      
let OmniCpp_DefaultNamespaces = ["std", "_GLIBCXX_STD"]      

au CursorMovedI,InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|silent! pclose|endif      
set completeopt=menuone,menu,longest,preview
```

I'll be very glad for all hints and answers!
Greetings,

Comment: What is the path to that `.vimrc`? Where did you install the plugin? Were you logged as root when you set it all up? `set nocp` is useless.

Comment: Tip: I found that [clang complete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302) works *way better* than OmniCppComplete: it uses libclang to parse your code "on the fly", so you get perfect suggestions without having to create tags.

Comment: romainl: path is ~/.vimrc and yes, I was logged as root. Matteo Italia: thank I'll also check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution (according to comment from romainl, thanks!). I have repeated the same process for non-root user.

I needed to modified my .vimrc a bit:

```
syntax on
filetype plugin on

set tags+=/home/USER_NAME/.vim/tags/stl/tags
set tags+=/home/USER_NAME/.vim/tags/gl/tags
set tags+=/home/USER_NAME/.vim/tags/sdl/tags

noremap <F12> :!ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<cr>
inoremap <F12> <Esc>:!ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<cr>

let OmniCpp_NamespaceSearch = 1
let OmniCpp_GlobalScopeSearch = 1
let OmniCpp_ShowAccess = 1
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteDot = 1
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteArrow = 1
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteScope = 1
let OmniCpp_DefaultNamespaces = ["std", "_GLIBCXX_STD"]

au CursorMovedI,InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|silent! pclose|endif
set completeopt=menuone,menu,longest,preview
```

First, I have repleaced

```
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/stl
```

with:

```
set tags+=/home/USER_NAME/.vim/tags/stl
```

Second, I needed to pointed "tags" file directly, so:

```
set tags+=/home/USER_NAME/.vim/tags/stl/tags
```

Other ways, It provides OmniCpp pattern not found. More info for example here: [vim omnicppcomplete pattern not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313943/vim-omnicppcomplete-pattern-not-found)

I hope it will be helpful for the others:)
Greetings and thanks for help. Now it works fine for non-root user as well.