# Vim omnicppcomplete pattern was not found

Tags: c++, macos, vim, autocomplete, omnicppcomplete

I'm working with Vim 7.4 on Mac OS.

I have installed [OmniCppComplete plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/OmniCppComplete) and tried to autocomplete c++. 
Of course I have installed the ctags.

Here is my .vimrc:
[image]

Now I have a simple project, which has only one class `Test` and one member function `func()` in the `Test`.
Then I execute the command below under the directory of my project:
`ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=c++ .`

In the `main`, I did as below:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void) {
    Test t;
    t.| // func( popup automatically
    std::| // ERROR
}
```

The member function can popup correctly but std:: can't -- `Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found`.

It doesn't seem that c++ standard library can be found correctly.

I also found another similar question:
[vim omnicppcomplete pattern not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313943/vim-omnicppcomplete-pattern-not-found)

I also tried to add tags in vim:

```
:set tags+=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/
```

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you should run ctags for system headers also (not just add path to tags variable within Vim).

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk It works! But I can only get something like `std::bind`, things like `std::cout` still doesn't work.

Comment: This is not answer to your question, but perhaps you could try [YouCompleteMe](https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/) - it provides exact C++ completion based on Clang.

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk  OK thanks. I ll try.